# Return stored procedure value for EF Core Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync

Tags: c#

I have this C# method which calls a valid stored procedure which performs insert statement. How do I get back the identity (primary key) after the insert statement.

```
public async Task AddFileFolderStructure(int id, string folderName, string folderType)
{
    var sproc_cmd = "dbo.AddFileFolderStructure";
    await Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"{sproc_cmd} {id}, {folderName}, {folderType}");
}
```

Here is my modified stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddFileFolderStructure]
    (@ParentId INT, 
     @FolderName VARCHAR(255), 
     @FolderType VARCHAR(255),
     @id int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [FileFolders] 
    VALUES (@ParentId, @FolderName, @FolderType)

    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    RETURN @id
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but it should work:

```
var output = new SqlParameter();
output.ParameterName = "@Id";
output.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

await Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync("EXEC {0} @param1={1} OUT,@param2={2}, @param3={3} " sproc_cmd,output,folderName,folderType);
```